# Intent filter for THERMAL_SHUTDOWN for Google Glass

Tags: android, google-glass

Is there any intent filter to detect thermal shutdown of google glass?

**We can detect the preshutdown warning (Glass is too hot) using the following intent in broadcast receiver:**

```
"com.google.android.glass.action.THERMAL_PRESHUTDOWN_WARNING"
```

I want a similar intent to detect the heat shutdown. I need an event when the thermal shutdown occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are existing inputs and sensors features of Google Glass as given in [Locations and Sensors](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/location-sensors#sensors).

However, as far as the documentation shows, the following Android sensors are still not supported:

- TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE
- TYPE_PRESSURE
- TYPE_PROXIMITY
- TYPE_RELATIVE_HUMIDITY
- TYPE_TEMPERATURE

Likewise, intent to detect the heat shutdown is not existing based from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/content/Intents).

Hope that helps.